# Count the number of comparison when compare two lists of string python

Tags: python, comparison, string-comparison, brute-force

I have homework that I cannot do correctly and not sure what's wrong with the code.

The exercise is :
with simple search or  Brute force find how many comparisons we make:

We have 2 lists that contain letters(string) and we compare them.Print out how many comparisons are made.

Example:

pattern= ABABC

text= ABBABACABCBAC

how I tried :

```
 def search(text,pattern):
    text=list(text)
    pattern=list(pattern)
    n=len(text)
    m=len(pattern)
    co=1
    l=0
    k=0
    while k<=m:
        if text[l] == pattern[k]:
            co+=1
            l+=1
            k+=1
        else:
            co+=1
            l+=1
            k=0
     c=co
    return "Simple matching made " + str(c) +" 
comparisons"
```

It should be 16, because we compare by letters and its like 3+1+1+4+1+2+1+3

We get 3 by: A=A means +1, B=B means 1,
B is not A so we add +1 but shift by one in the text.

Comment: could you explain in more detail how you reached 3+1+1+4+1+2+1+3 I think I understand the first 3, but if I do then the next number would be 2...

Comment: Yes. So we shift by one means we compare  BBABA with ABABC. But if we compare the first letters we see its not eqaul so we compared one so we add one

Comment: The next one is also starting with B so +1. The fourth one we have ABACA so we compare: we have A +1, we have B +1, A +1, C which we compare so +1 but its not B so we shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scripted something that does what I think you are looking for, but I think you are missing a term at the end unless I did it wrong.
    pattern = 'ABABC'
    text = 'ABBABACABCBAC'

```
def search(text, pattern):
    slices = len(text) - len(pattern)
    for i in range(0, slices + 1):
        count = 0
        text_to_compare = text[i:i + len(pattern)]
        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            count += 1
            if pattern[j] == text_to_compare[j]:
                continue
            else:
                break
        print("{} -> {}".format(text_to_compare, count))

search(text, pattern)
```

This outputs

> ABBAB -> 3
>
> BBABA -> 1
>
> BABAC -> 1
>
> ABACA -> 4
>
> BACAB -> 1
>
> ACABC -> 2
>
> CABCB -> 1
>
> ABCBA -> 3
>
> BCBAC -> 1

It can be adapted for total count like:

```
def search(text, pattern):
    total_count = 0
    slices = len(text) - len(pattern)
    for i in range(0, slices + 1):
        count = 0
        text_to_compare = text[i:i + len(pattern)]
        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            count += 1
            total_count += 1
            if pattern[j] == text_to_compare[j]:
                continue
            else:
                break
        print("{} -> {}".format(text_to_compare, count))
    print("Total count: {}".format(total_count))
```

Which outputs the same as before but also with:

> Total count: 17

Is this what you are looking for? I can explain what parts you don't understand :)

Comment: Yes i think it is the correct one. Can you explain the last print parts because i never saw or used the "{} - >{} ". format

Comment: @werlless It takes the arguments supplied on the right and puts them into your string. I was just using the default mode where the first variable supplied to `.format()` fills the first {} in the string and so on. Its similar to the % operator for strings. There are many other ways to use it though so here is a tutorial to cover them https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/